# The USB ethernet interface dies after a few minutes on pizero w?

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I am using usb0 for ethernet while working on an application. On the device, I can connect to it just fine after it boots, but after a few minutes the device stops transmitting any data over usb0. wlan0 continues to work just fine, so the device is up and running just usb0/network gadget interface dies.

Nothing in dmesg or syslog?

Any thoughts on what I should look for or maybe I just have a bad unit? Same card in another unit seems to work just fine and doesn't hang up, so I'm thinking it might just be a bad unit.

Comment: Are both the USB0 to Ethernet and WLAN0 both working and responding at the same time? I'd try diagnosing by seeing if the USB0 failure still occurs with WLAN0 disabled.

Comment: What operating system with what version do you use?

Comment: Yes, WLAN0 is disabled since I am working on Bluetooth NLE to setup wifi. This is why I need the USB0 interface. I am using Buster (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster))